# How can we live off of all the food

Tags: food, livestock

Just today, I noticed I had some hotdog buns in my fridge that I had left over from the hogdogs I previously ate. You know, the two extra right? Well it's been 2 months since and I forgot buns so I found them in the fridge and they still smelt okay and tasted fine. It's been a hour already since I had them, so I don't think I am going to get sick. So it got me thinking...

So starting tomorrow suddenly nobody got sick from eating spoiled/bad food, how would that change the world? Could we solve world hunger by stockpiling popular foods such as pizza? What about donuts? Do foods such as twinkies become a thing of the past now that all the foods last forever? What happens to animals?

Comment: I think you might have to answer the last question for us.  In *theory*, if nobody is getting sick from spoiled food, that suggests that the decomposition of dead animals may have changed drastically, and the way it changed may affect people's answers.

Comment: Are you asking what would happen if food didn't spoil, or what would happen if humans could eat spoiled food without getting sick?

Comment: White hotdog buns?  Full of preservatives :-)  But most anything based on flour (bread, cakes, etc) will last for a long time if it dries out, so that mold does not grow on it.  Same's true for a lot of meat, fruit, &c.  If it is dried properly - jerky, dried fruit, &c - it will last for years.

Answer (score 5):

There is enough food on Earth to feed [all the humans](https://www.wfp.org/hunger/faqs). In fact, more humans are [overweight](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-35933691) than underweight. The problem with hunger is one of distribution.

- In a few areas, security conditions do not permit the delivery of food.
- In more areas, economic conditions do not allow the people to earn enough money to buy food at going market rates. The markets would rather let food spoil on the shelves than give it away, which is entirely rational for a *capitalist* actor trying to maximize profits.

The capitalist system is very efficient by some measures. Food supply for everybody isn't one of them.

Comment: O.m.! Why are you always answering off topic questions?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon, I answer some questions which are voted off-topic by **other** people **afterwards**. Usually I don't start answering questions if there are close votes, but sometimes a few votes come in by the time I've finished writing. And of course it is impossible to answer closed questions. I often check for new, unanswered questions, so it happens that I answer before there is a consensus.

Comment: Well, you should at least look at the question yourself and decide whether or not it is on topic. And if you so consistently think questions are not, you should really look around at closed questions and read more about the scope of the site.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon, when the question is closed my answer is effectively gone as well. So the only problem would be that the original poster feels encouraged by my answer ...

Comment: What happens is you benefit by going against the site's code of conduct, and encouraging bad questions. You leave people with a little help, but also confused as to whether it should have been closed. Overall I'd compare you to those _capitalist_ actors you mentioned that sell food and don't care about anyone. (Because actors = store owners, right?)

Comment: @XandarTheZenon, the benefit is below the rounding error of the rep display. I don't think I can get more privileges that way ...